# displaying data using join im my webpage

Tags: php, sql

hi all i am new to php and i am developing a website i am using inner join to retrive data it work fine in sql, but when i using in php it showing error and not displayed pls help me  owth the code. here is my code

```
<? do
  {
    ?>  
      <tr>

        <td><?php echo $fet_2['hemember.name'];?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $fet_2['ccase.comments'];?></td> 

    <?php }while($fet_2=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))?>

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT hemember.name, ccase.comments
 FROM hemember
 INNER JOIN ccase ON hemember.memid = ccase.he
 ORDER BY ccase.date desc");
```

Comment: mysql_query() is a php/mysql method ..take it under <?php ?>  tag as well

Comment: show us the complete code what you are trying.

Comment: what error its showing..??

Answer (score 1):

First things first:

> Please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are no longer
>   maintained and are [deprecated as of PHP
>   5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead learn about [prepared
>   statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either
>   [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you
>   can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you to
>   choose. If you care to learn, here is good [PDO
>   tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Now you can do it like this (with **mysqli**):

```html
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Comments</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
$db = new mysqli("db_host", "db_user", "db_pwd", "db_name");
$qry = "SELECT hemember.name, ccase.comments
          FROM hemember INNER JOIN ccase ON hemember.memid = ccase.he
         ORDER BY ccase.date desc";

echo "<tr>";
if ($result = $db->query($qry)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<td>".$row['hemember.name']. "</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['ccase.comments']. "</td>";
    }
$result->close();
}
echo "</tr>";
$db->close();
?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Code wasn't tested.

Comment: i ll try it and get back to you petern